# Inequalities with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Not sure where I'm going wrong...

Question:
Show that if $|z| = R>2$ and $\Im(z)\geq 0$, then
$$\left|\frac{e^{z}}{z}\right| \leq \frac{1}{R}.$$

My attempt doesn't seem to show it holds, and also, that it doesn't matter whether or not the imaginary part is non-negative (or not).

$$LHS = \left|\frac{e^{z}}{z}\right|\\ = \frac{|e^{x}e^{iy}|}{|z|}\\ = \frac{|e^x |\cdot 1}{|z|} \qquad \text{regardless whether or not $z$ was real or not}\\ = \frac{|e^x|}{R}$$
Now the inequality (to be proven) is only true when $e^x \leq 1 \iff x < 0$....

edit: The $|z| =R>2$ condition also seems irrelevant... as it means $z$ is outside the circle with radius $2$ (centred at the origin), so $z$ can still attain any possible $x$ value. It seems as if the question didn't give any relevant information, and gave irrelevant ones instead... am I missing something?

Comment: The inequality fails if $z=3$. Maybe you posted  an incorrect version of the actual problem? Check the source.

Comment: Maybe your inequality is $\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\right| \leq \frac{1}{R}$. Any possible typo?

Comment: Just checked again and it's the same inequality as I wrote above.  
@RobertZ Ah maybe, that uses the $\Im(z)$ condition but not the $R$ one though

Comment: Where does this inequality come from? Book? Notes in the web?

Comment: It came from my University's lecture problems under the "Complex Analysis Inequalities" section. Not sure where the professor sourced it from.

Comment: So it's surely a typo. Try Robert Z's version instead. Or email the prof.